# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Here is my code, I'm not sure why I keep getting the error

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-6MK4S6G;Initial Catalog=Domingo;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Job]
                                          ([JobCardNo], [CustomerNo], [JobTypeID], [Days])
                                      VALUES ('" + TxtNo.ToString() + "', '" + Txtcust.ToString() + "', '" + TxtID.ToString() + "','" +Txtdays.ToString() + "')", con);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Response.Write("Data created successfully");
    con.Close();
}
```

Heres my table in SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Job] ([JobCardNo], [CustomerNo], [JobTypeID],[Days])
VALUES (<JobCardNo, int,>, <CustomerNo, int,>, <JobTypeID, int,>, <Days, int,>)
```

I keep getting this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int.'

when running the code.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). It is better to use parameterized query than using concatenation

Comment: You can't just call .ToString() method on a textbox and expect to get the value from the textbox. You need to access the value through the Text property. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox). And of course, never concatenate strings to form a SQL query like you're doing. Instead, use parameterized queries to help defend against SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: also: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What does [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) actually do? It does not do what you think - you have more to learn about controls and how to use them. Start by looking at the properties of that class - and perhaps a tutorial about using controls in an application generally.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem. As the comments said, [TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox?view=netframework-4.8) does not use the ToString method but the Text property.

I made the following changes to your code, you could refer to the following code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"constr");
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Job]
                                          ([JobCardNo], [CustomerNo], [JobTypeID], [Days])
                                      VALUES ('" + int.Parse(TxtNo.Text) + "', '" + int.Parse(Txtcust.Text) + "', '" + int.Parse(TxtID.Text) + "','" + int.Parse(Txtdays.Text) + "')", con);
      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      Response.Write("Data created successfully");
      con.Close();
    }
```

The result is shown in the picture:
[image]

Comment: Hi, @ taahir mia. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.

Comment: Queries involving user input should ALWAYS be parameterized - this technique is subject to sql injection.